# how to hide all windows except editor window in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ide

In Eclipse when you click twice on the tab of the editors Eclipse hide all other windows except the one you write code in and when you do that again(clicking the tab of the document all windows comeback again).

Is there a similar feature in Visual Studio 2013?

**Update:** I found Auto Hide in Window Menu, but I don't want auto hide, I want to click something to hide windows and click again to show them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

View | Full Screen

(In my key bindings: <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>.)

However, double clicking on an editor tab also works, this is provided by one of the extensions I use, but I'm not sure which.)

Comment: does not works for me. I use shift+alt+enter but it is slightly different as it makes editor window full screen.

Answer (score 4):

As a programmer i love shortcut keys which is very helpful for productive work. I've search question as you mentioned. But i did not get proper answer. then i've searched solution for me which might helpful to you.

**Step 1**: Go to visual studio 
**Step 2**: From tool menu open Options menu 
**Step 3**: Go Environment -> Keyboard 
**Step 4**: Select item **Window.AutoHideAll** from list 
**Step 5**: Set short cut in "Press shortcut keys textbox". I've set **Ctrl+Alt+]** then click on Assign & then ok. 
**Step 6**: Final step. Use above shortcut to **hide all window** other than **editor window.**

Comment: This is ok for one direction to maximize. Is there also a way to unhide them? I did not find a command for this.

Answer (score 0):

Richards answer does work, but has the side effect of maximizing the whole of Visual Studio as well. Sometimes (e.g. when comparing editor text to some other text), I would like Visual Studio to only take half the screen. A solution I found in Visual Studio 2019 was:

1. Window | Save Window Layout (call it something like Normal layout)
2. Unpin all the other panes you don't want to see, ToolBox, Solution Explorer, Build Results etc. Typically Left, Right and Bottom
3. Window | Save Window Layout, call it say maximized Editor.
4. Window | Apply Window Layout, you can choose Normal or Maximized editor
5. Visual Studio assigns these shortcut keys automatically of Ctrl+Alt+1 and Ctrl+Alt+2 to the first two Apply Window Layout choices